# WatchKit2 error on Archive - WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions

Tags: app-store-connect, watchkit, watchos-2, info.plist

I have this error after Archive of watchkit app.

*error: WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions. Verify that the value of NSExtensionPointIdentifier in your WatchKit Extension's Info.plist is set to com.apple.watchkit.*

My Info.plist is like this:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.company.nomeapp.watchkit</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.watchkit</string>
</dict>
```

Build and run on device and simulator works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently (though it didn't build correctly), the problem for me ended up being Mach-O Type was set to static

Go to build settings of watchkit app/extension and make sure:

> Mach-O Type = Executable